# subset a matrix multiple times using list columns

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I'm looking to subset a matrix using df columns in a list format. For example I'd like to subset the matrix `otu_table` using the list `metadata_river` which contains 37 dfs (`Alabama` in this example) all with the column `sequence_id`.  My expected output `al_otu` is correct, but I'm looking to have 37 unique outputs to represent the 37 dfs in the list.  Would the solution be a loop of some kind?

```
al_otu <- otu_table[,metadata_river$Alabama$sequence_id]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a toy example that works, if I'm interpreting your question correctly:

```r
# Matrix with 10 colnames, a to j
mat <- matrix(rnorm(30), ncol = 10)
colnames(mat) <- letters[1:10]

# List of dfs, where common colname `sequence_id` includes 5 random
# character values mapping to a to j in the matrix colnames
set.seed(123)
list_of_dfs <- list(
  df1 = data.frame(sequence_id = sample(letters[1:10], 5)),
  df2 = data.frame(sequence_id = sample(letters[1:10], 5)),
  df3 = data.frame(sequence_id = sample(letters[1:10], 5))
)

# Query `mat` with `sequence_id` column from each df
# Will produce a list of 3 matrices, each subset to the
# columns specified by df1$sequence_id, df2$sequence_id, and df3$sequence_id
lapply(list_of_dfs, \(df) {
  mat[, df$sequence_id]
})
```

Output of lapply: a list of length 3, each containing a matrix

```r
# $df1
#                c          j          b          h          f
# [1,]  0.82553984 -0.7717918  0.2382129 -0.5996083 -0.1453936
# [2,] -0.05568601  0.2865486 -1.0488931 -0.1294107 -1.1655448
# [3,] -0.78438222 -1.2205120  1.2947633  0.8867361 -0.8185157

# $df2
#                e          d          f          h         a
# [1,] -1.08569914 -0.7335032 -0.1453936 -0.5996083 0.5038124
# [2,] -0.08542326 -0.2158654 -1.1655448 -0.1294107 2.5283366
# [3,]  1.07061054 -0.3349128 -0.8185157  0.8867361 0.5490967

# $df3
#               j           e           c          h         a
# [1,] -0.7717918 -1.08569914  0.82553984 -0.5996083 0.5038124
# [2,]  0.2865486 -0.08542326 -0.05568601 -0.1294107 2.5283366
# [3,] -1.2205120  1.07061054 -0.78438222  0.8867361 0.5490967
```